# What do we mean by "solve the initial differentation problem for y"?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm asked to evaluate an indefinate integral $\int P dx$ by substitution. This is the first question:

$$ P= \frac {x^5+1}{x^2+1} $$

and my answer is

$$(\ln⁡(x^2+1))/2+x^4/4-x^2/2+\arctan⁡(x)+C$$

The second question is "Hence, solve the initial problem $\frac {dy}{dx} = P$   for y, where y = 1 at x = 0".

--- **What do we mean by "solving the initial problem for y"?**

My guess is to find the constant C by putting y = 1 and x = 0 into the answer $(\ln⁡(x^2+1))/2+x^4/4-x^2/2+\arctan⁡(x)+C$.

May I know if I guess correctly? Thank you for answering.

Comment: I think you are right. Just solve the C.

Comment: You are correct. Make $y=1$ and $x=0$ to get $C$

Comment: Therfore C=1

Then the ans is (ln(x2+1))/2+x4/4−x2/2+arctan(x)+C(ln⁡(x2+1))/2+x4/4−x2/2+arctan⁡(x)+1

Comment: Perhaps you may be more familiar with "initial value problem". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem